# Selecting top N records per group in DynamoDB

Tags: nosql, greatest-n-per-group, amazon-dynamodb

Is NoSQL in general, and DynamoDB in particular, well suited to performing [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) type queries, as compared to MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB support only 2 index and can only be queried efficiently on these.

1. hash key
2. range key (*optional*)

Using DynamoDB to find the biggest values in a random "row" is **not** a good idea at all. Querying on a random row implies **scanning** the whole dataset which will cost you a lot of money.

Nonetheless, if your data is properly modeled, **query** method may be used to find the **biggest range_key for a given hash_key**

Here is how to proceed:

- Set the has_key
- Set no filter for the range_key
- limit the result count to 1
- scan the index backward